# when change checkbox from Yes to No not sent value correctly to submit function when click approve button?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I work on asp.net MVC application I face issue when change check box (Yes to  No) OR (No to Yes)

not detect value true or false  correctly .

I have two check box

Yes represent true value

No represent false value

I don't need to change checkbox to radio button because this is user requirement as `checkbox` .

when select Yes or No for first time it send value correctly

but when I select Yes or No for second time it not send value correctly and send only value false to approve button when select Yes or No .

What I Try

1 - User UI for Yes or No

```
<td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
      @Html.Label("Did you try to retain the staff?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
      <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuff" name="RetainStuff" value="true" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == true ? "checked" : "") />
          Yes
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuff" name="RetainStuff" value="false" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == false ? "checked" : "") />
          No
      </div>
  </td>
   <a id="approveControlsId" onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve </a>
```

2 - when change Yes or No check box to get value true or false of retain stuff checkbox i use jQuery as below :

```
 $('.retaindtuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
     $('.retaindtuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     $('#RetainStuff').val(selectedValue);

 });
```

3 - when click approve button value of check box
not send correctly to `submit()` function

```
function submit() {
        
            var ResignationRequester = new Object();
            ResignationRequester.RequestNo = document.getElementById("RequestNo").innerHTML.trim();
   
  

        var RetainStuffElement = document.getElementById("RetainStuff");

        if (RetainStuffElement) {
           
            var RetainStuffElementExist = document.querySelector('input[name="RetainStuff"]:checked');
          
            if (RetainStuffElementExist && RetainStuffElementExist.value === "false") {
                ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = RetainStuffElementExist.value;
                
                ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = null;
                return false;
            } 
            else if (RetainStuffElementExist) {
                ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = RetainStuffElementExist.value;
               
            } 
            else {
                ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = null;
                
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = "";

        }
 
            if (ResignationRequester != null) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("ApprovalIndex", "Resignation")',
                    data: JSON.stringify(ResignationRequester),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            
                    datatype: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        
                    }
                    
                });
            }
    }
```

4 - action result calling `ApprovalIndex` on resignation controller

```
[HttpPost] 
public async Task<ActionResult> ApprovalIndex(ResignationRequester REQ) 
{ 
//update approve status 
}
```

so why checkbox yes or no working on first time only

Image for page i work on it

[image: image show issue]

**Updated post**

can you give me solution applied on current status
and without using form

meaning i need to depend on name or class `retaindtuff-checkbox`

Comment: A part from the fact that your use of checkbox is not correct (what if the user checks both?) having the same name and id is surely confusing. I think the code take always the first one and ignore whatever value is in the second one. I think you should name the two checkboxes differently.

Comment: so thanks for support but i don't know how to solve issues of checkbox it send value wrong when select yes or no checkbox

Comment: so can you help me please to solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can separate your representation in checkboxes from the value you intend to submit. Here I created two checkboxes and a text input (the only reason it's a text and not a hidden was to make it easy to track what happens, but in your actual HTML you might want to make it a hidden input) and whenever the checkboxes are being tackled, the value of this RetainStuff input is being updated accordingly. If you were to submit a form with an element having the name of `RetainStuff`, then its value at the time of form submission would be submitted. So if it is being updated correctly, then your form would work well if you applied this idea.

```js
let context = document.getElementById("myform");
let chk_yes = context.querySelector(".chk_yes");
let chk_no = context.querySelector(".chk_no");
let RetainStuff = context.querySelector("[name=RetainStuff]");

chk_yes.addEventListener("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.value = this.checked ? "yes" : "no";
    chk_no.checked = !this.checked;
});

chk_no.addEventListener("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.value = this.checked ? "no" : "yes";
    chk_yes.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="someaction">
    <label>Yes <input class="chk_yes" type="checkbox" checked></label>
    <label>No <input class="chk_no" type="checkbox"></label>
    <input type="text" name="RetainStuff" value="yes">
</form>
```

EDIT

Another snippet, which is more akin to your structure:

```js
let context = document.querySelector(".retaindtuff-checkbox").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
let chk_yes = context.querySelector(".retaindtuff-checkbox[value=true]");
let chk_no = context.querySelector(".retaindtuff-checkbox[value=false]");
let RetainStuff = context.querySelector("[name=RetainStuff]");

chk_yes.addEventListener("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.value = this.checked ? "yes" : "no";
    chk_no.checked = !this.checked;
});

chk_no.addEventListener("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.value = this.checked ? "no" : "yes";
    chk_yes.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

```html
<table><tr>
<td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
      @Html.Label("Did you try to retain the staff?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
      <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" checked />
          Yes
          </label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="false" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" />
          No
          </label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="RetainStuff" value="yes">
  </td>
  </tr></table>
   <a id="approveControlsId" onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve </a>
```

EDIT2

Here I'm making it more jQuery-ish, as per our discussion in the comment section.

```js
let context = $(".retaindtuff-checkbox").parent().parent().parent();
let chk_yes = context.find(".retaindtuff-checkbox[value=true]");
let chk_no = context.find(".retaindtuff-checkbox[value=false]");
let RetainStuff = context.find("[name=RetainStuff]");

chk_yes.on("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.val(this.checked ? "yes" : "no");
    chk_no.prop("checked", !this.checked);
});

chk_no.on("input", function() {
    RetainStuff.val(this.checked ? "no" : "yes");
    chk_yes.prop("checked", !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>
<td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
      @Html.Label("Did you try to retain the staff?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
      <div class="col-md-7">
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" checked />
          Yes
          </label>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" value="false" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" />
          No
          </label>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="RetainStuff" value="yes">
  </td>
  </tr></table>
   <a id="approveControlsId" onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve </a>
```

Comment: I appreciated your support but can you help me solving issue without using form and on current status please

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz you do not have to use `form`. I used it in my example. You can add the input of my example with the name of `RetainStuff` and remove the `RetainStuff` name from your checkboxes and of course add the functionalities I have specified. If you need further help with your current try, I can help you with that too, but you will need to edit your question then with the current HTML you have.

Comment: how to replace context with ??? because i don't use form

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz do you have a single context to work with or multiple contexts with the same class name?

Comment: can you please show me on my code i use it please

Comment: i use only one class name retaindtuff-checkbox and only one name retainstuff

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz my answer depends on your answer to my question. Please answer my question (do you have multiple contexts with the class of retaindtuff-checkbox or is that a unique element in your HTML) and then I will provide further information.

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz okay, so your answer to my question is that inside your HTML you have a single such context. Editing my answer accordingly.

Comment: can you apply your answer please on my html below  <div class="col-md-7">
          <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuff" name="RetainStuff" value="true" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == true ? "checked" : "") />
          Yes
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuff" name="RetainStuff" value="false" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == false ? "checked" : "") />
          No
      </div>

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz as I said, I was already editing my answer. Now I have edited my answer. I have 1. Removed your repetitive id from the checkboxes, because that made your HTMLinvalid, 2. Ensured that your submit link is outside the table, because it's not sitting well in-between your td elements, 3. Wrapped labels around your checkboxes, so clicking on the Yes/No text will change their state as you probably expect, 4. Removed your logic that determines whether the elements are to be checked initially because that did not help my tests, you will need to put that back

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz and finally, I used your structure as the point of departure and applied the idea I suggested upon it.

Comment: very good excellent this is exactly what i need only remaining thing how to modify my jQuery without using event listener $('.retaindtuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
     $('.retaindtuff-checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', false);
     var selectedValue = $(this).val();
     $('#RetainStuff').val(selectedValue);

 });

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz to clarify: is the current code working well, but you prefer it to be more jQuery-ish? Let me know if that's the case and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: yes working but i need it jQuery

Comment: @ahmedabdelaziz made a further edit to make it more jQuery-like. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.