# How to get value of checkbox true or false on javascript submit function?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work on asp.net MVC web application my issue can't get value of checkbox on submit function javascript .

if I select checkbox Yes then value true on submit function .
if I select checkbox No then value false on submit function .
if i not select Yes or No then value will be false

I call javascript submit function when click on button approve to submit value of checkbox .

my code

```html
         <td style="width: 50%; font-weight: bold; padding-top: 10px;">
         @Html.Label("Did you try to retain the staff?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
         <div class="col-md-7">
             <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuffTrue" name="RetainStuff" value="true" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == true ? "checked" : "") />
             Yes
             &nbsp;&nbsp;
             <input type="checkbox" id="RetainStuffFalse" name="RetainStuff" value="false" class="retaindtuff-checkbox" @(Model.RetainStuff == false ? "checked" : "") />
             No
         </div>
     </td>
      <a id="approveControlsId" onclick="submit();" class="btn btn-primary" style="min-width: 100px;margin-top:5px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i> Approve </a>
```

```
    public class ResignationRequester
    {
    public bool? RetainStuff {get;set;}
    }
```

so in jQuery what I write here to get value checked or selected

```
    $('.retaindtuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
        // what I write here 
    });
```

And on submit function javascript how to get value of checkbox if yes then true or No then
false

```
    function submit() {
        var ResignationRequester = new Object();
       ResignationRequester.RetainStuff =????
      // how to pass value of retainstuff here 
    }
```

**Updated post**

I must select checkbox Yes or No
but not accept to make both checked
if i leave yes or no without checked then `RetainStuff` will be null
Must be Yes or No checked

Comment: Based on your design, both of your checkboxes can be checked at the same time. You may consider using radio button to avoid checking on Yes and No.

Comment: can you help me please without use radio button because this is required from user

Comment: if i check box yes then value will be true if select checkbox No then value will be false and i can;t leave yes or no checkbox not checked at least one must be check

Comment: There no language named `java script` there is `java` or `javascript`. there is no hypothetical "scripting" language based on the java language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, your current approach will allow both checkboxes to be checked at the same time. Thus, you need to control the checkboxes so that when one of them is checked, another one must be unchecked programmatically.

You can get the checked checkbox value via `$("input[type=checkbox].retaindtuff-checkbox:checked").val()`.

```js
$('.retaindtuff-checkbox').on('change', function () {
  var value = $(this).val();

  // Uncheck another checkbox, both checkboxes are mutually exclusive
  if (value == 'true') $('#RetainStuffFalse').prop('checked', false);
  else $('#RetainStuffTrue').prop('checked', false);
});

function submit() {
  var ResignationRequester = new Object();
  ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = $("input[type=checkbox].retaindtuff-checkbox:checked").val();

  // Convert to boolean
  // ResignationRequester.RetainStuff = $("input[type=checkbox].retaindtuff-checkbox:checked").val() == "true";
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fr7bun?file=index.html);

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853017/when-change-checkbox-from-yes-to-no-not-sent-value-correctly-to-submit-function/77853188#77853188

Comment: thanks for your reply very good answer this is exactly what i need can you tell me how to convert to boolean please

Comment: The commented code is converting to boolean.